# In Akka, how can network delays be simulated?

Tags: java, akka, delay, distributed-system, raft

I have a question that is more of a design one rather than a coding one.

I'm currently using Akka (we're transitioning from Classic to Typed) to implement a Raft cluster, using the Java version. Our assignment requires the cluster - like the paper implementation - to operate on harsh network conditions, and as such I would like to implement Akka-side a way to systematically delay messages. Timings and selectivity do not matter - e.g., assume we want to delay ALL messages going through the system by 200ms.u

My idea was to use Routers - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/routers.html - but I would like to know what's the best approach to write something that is both scalable and does not add unpredictable bugs (like using `Thread.sleep()` does, which delays message queue handling)

EDIT: The raft cluster is hosted on a single machine, so transmission is basically instantaneous now, and any interaction is handled by Akka itself. No network stack is ever involed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can accomplish this, but note that in Akka you can explicitly model the network by sending messages to an actor A through another actor B, e.g. by wrapping the messages in an envelope class which has the destination and the message.  Actor B then forwards the message actor A and can use Akka's scheduling utilities (they differ somewhat between [Classic](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html) and [Typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#scheduling-messages-to-self)) to delay the send; actor B can also simulate arbitrary message loss.

Answer (score 0):

Based on understanding your question, since you are looking at network level, you should be taking a look at chaos testing tools.

You can check for bunch of these tools here:
https://github.com/dastergon/awesome-chaos-engineering

Comment: uhm, not, maybe I explained myself badly. I was looking for a way to use the Akka library to implement network latency from a simulated side. The raft cluster is hosted on a single machine, so transmission is basically instantaneous now, and any interaction is handled by Akka itself. I'm updating the question to make myself more clear

Comment: I think then in that case, what levi ramsey suggested is the approach that you should follow.